# Using the word user for a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I checked the list of reserved words which can be found here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

and I could not find the word 'user' but still I have seen alot of people say that you should not use the word 'user' for a table name but rather use a word like person instead. I don't understand why this is an issue because I could not find it in the reserved word list.

In what circumstances would it be bad to use the word 'user' as a table name? Because when I try using that name it looks like everything I do works as expected so I don't understand why this is something I should avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a reserved word in other SQL dialects (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) so it's best to play it safe. What if you want to transport your database to a different DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html

User is mysql account.

CREATE USER creates a new row in the mysql.user

like

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is use plural names for the tables (users, persons...)

Is more correct say "the users table" and "an user" when refers to one row.

Comment: That won't help the OP, because the list of reserved words also contains plurals (LINES, KEYS, REFERENCES etc). So this is not a solution.

Comment: of course, I know this is not the solution but is a good practice

Answer (score 0):

You have an article here: http://sql-info.de/mysql/notes/gotchas/user-is-not-a-reserved-word.html

There it says that `USER` is not treated as a reserved word by MySQL, but other SQL specifications including ANSI does reserve it.

Note that MySQL offers the safe mechanism of using quotes to prevent errors due to conflicts with reserved words.

This is extensively documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html